# nuget.exe doesn't restore all packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

When I run:

```
nuget.exe restore c:\path\to\my.sln
```

It creates directory c:\path\to\packages, but it only restores one of 4 nuget packages used by the solution. It only restores EntityFramework.6.2.0.

When I open the same solution in Visual Studio and rebuild, then my c:\path\to\packages\ directory also contains:

- EPPlus.4.5.3.1\
- NPOI.2.4.1\
- SharpZipLib.1.0.0\

The solution only contains a single project.

Why does nuget.exe restore not restore all packages, instead of just restoring one of them?

Is there some command line argument to retrieve non-Microsoft packages? I didn't see one in the Nuget docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated nuget,

```
nuget.exe restore c:\path\to\my.sln
```

...and that seems to have solved the issue. I was previously using version 2.X.

Comment: what kind of project is this?

Comment: @karann-MSFT C# console application using .NET 4.5.1